# SSRS Not Saving Printer Properties

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

As the subject says, I have an SSRS report that needs to have its printer setup a certain way, such as changing page orientation from Portrait to Landscape, in order to print correctly.

However, every time I go to do a test print of this report in Report Viewer, when I check the printer properties, they've all reverted back to the defaults. None of the changes I made were saved past the printing in that moment when I clicked OK.

Changing the settings in the printer itself has met the same result. Has anyone else encountered this? I am using SQL Server 2014.

EDIT: I forgot you can make SSRS reports in Visual Studio, so to be clear I'm using SSRS Report Builder.

Following Russel's response, I have confirmed that my page width and height are set correctly for landscape printing. I hadn't changed the margins from their 1" defaults before now, so hopefully that will yield some result. In any case, here's what my settings look like right now.

[image]

Comment: @SeanLange That question is about VS.

Answer (score 0):

In VS, select the Properties tab and in the dropdown at the very top, right under "Properties", select "Report". If you scroll down you'll see settings for "Page", including Margins and Page Size. If it should print landscape, swap the PageSize settings: 11in wide and 8.5in high. Set appropriate margins and be aware that if you have 1" left and right margins, your report data can only be 9" wide. Those properties should carry through to the printer.

[image]

Comment: Shoot, I should have mentioned that I'm using SSRS Report Builder, not Visual Studio. Thanks for the reminder, Russel. Please see my update above.

Comment: Your PageSize parameters should still be 8.5x11, unless you're printing on something tiny, like a credit card? It's not the size of the printable area on the report, it's the actual size of the paper it's printing on. By setting to 8.5x11 or 11x8.5, you're telling it whether it's portrait or landscape. Does that make sense?